# How to build and install dependencies from CMake

Tags: cmake

I am trying to create CMakeLists.txt, that can be able to build a number of other projects. My goal is to simplify building some libraries of particular project.

I have a directory called 'dependencies' with CMakeLists.txt, and there are some source code directories inside. Structure like this:

```
dependencies/
├── zlib   (source code directory with it's own CMakeLists.txt)
├── libpng (source code directory with it's own CMakeLists.txt)
├── 3d lib (source code directory with it's own CMakeLists.txt, that uses zlib and libpng)
├── CMakeLists.txt
```

At this moment I have next content in the root CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.15)
project(myProject)

set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../lib)
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../lib)
#### NEED TO ADD HERE ####
```

I want to do next things for all these subprojects (zlib, libpng and 3d lib):

1. Configure project with CMake;
2. Build this project in both: Debug and Release configurations;
3. Run install.

I need all these libraries to be installed to CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX, because '3d lib' will look for zlib and libpng in that directory. And by the time, when '3d lib's CMakeLists.txt will be processing, all previous libs has to be already installed, otherwise CMake fails finding zlib and libpng.

So is there a way to append my root CMakeLists.txt to do that? Of course, I can manually run CMake for all dependencies, but I think CMake are able to do all this stuff autonomously.

Comment: I am doing that on Windows, using Visual Studio compiler for this project.

Comment: soooo `add_subdirectory`?

Comment: Thank you for your reply) This is really worked after I did some research.

Answer (score 0):

`add_subdirectory` was really the solution for this problem.

When I tried it for the first time I had some errors and thought that this was because some of these targets depend on others of them. But I was wrong, `add_subdirectory` is what I need.

Comment: pro tip: do `add_subdirectory(... EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)` so you don't compile stuff that you do not need.